# Android App to MySql without internet connection

Tags: android, mysql

we are new to android dev and currently creating an app in which it has to connect with an external database to fetch data (text only). the only problem is that we dont know how to connect the app to the database. is it possible to fetch data OFFLINE? please. i need your answers. :'(

Answer (score 1):

IT is not possilbe at ALL...its like TV without REMOTE...you need internet connection to create the apps with the help of MYSQL DATABASE SERVER....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are familiar with the concepts internet and connectivity but an external database can only be accessed through internet connection. To connect to a mysql database you are likely to need some php scripts.

This is a nice tutorial on how to do this:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, accessing an external mysql database without internet connection is not possible. But you can store your data in a local database using sqllite and sync it with your server, if the internet connection is available. A good tutorial, how to use sqllite with android is shown here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html